# js deactivate spacebar when typing in textfield

Tags: javascript, audio, textfield, space

I am creating a music player which uses the spacebar to pause and play audio, now is it possible to know if someone is currently typing in a textfield, because right now, if this user types in a textfield and audio is playing, when the user presses space the audio pauses, I would like basically that when the user is not in a  textfield that a user can just play and pause audio, but when the user is typing that this function is disabled so the audio keeps playing. The code below, is the code I'm am current using for detecting when space is pressed;

```
//IF Space bar is Pressed
$(window).keypress(function(e) {
if(e.keyCode == 32) {
    if(document.getElementById('audio').paused){
        if(document.getElementById('video').style.display=="block"){

        }
        else{
            document.getElementById('audio').play();
            document.getElementById('pause').style.display="block"; 
            document.getElementById('play').style.display="none";
        }
    }
    else{
        if(document.getElementById('video').style.display=="block"){

        }
        else{
            document.getElementById('audio').pause();
            document.getElementById('pause').style.display="none";
            document.getElementById('play').style.display="block";
        }
    }
}
});
//END IF Space bar is pressed
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the event sources `tagName` attribute:

```
function(e) {
 e = e || event;
 var el = e.srcElement || e.target,
     cando = !(/textarea|input/i.test(el.tagName));

 if(cando && e.keyCode == 32)  {
   /etc.
 }
}
```

Comment: Genius :), I don't understand most of that, I'll have to read up about it but thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Check if a textarea has focus

```
if(e.keyCode == 32 && !text_area_has_focus) { ...
```

Logic for that could be something like this, if you're willing to use jQuery:

```
if(e.keyCode == 32 && !$('input[type=text]:focus').length) { ...
```

Comment: hmmmmmm, thats not working, thats completely stopped audio being paused or played via space bar regardless if typing or not :(

Comment: @Lenny, did you just copy paste that? Because you actually have to implement the logic for setting text_area_has_focus....

Comment: hmmmm, yeh that's the bit I'm stuck with I understand what you did, but do you know how to detect if a textfield has focus?

Answer (score 1):

You could also try

```
if(e.keyCode == 32 && document.activeElement != document.getElementById('someTextBox'))
```

New code

```
//IF Space bar is Pressed
$(window).keypress(function(e) {
if(e.keyCode == 32) {
    var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

    for(var item in inputs)
    {
        if(inputs[item] == document.activeElement)
            return;
    }

    if(document.getElementById('audio').paused){
        if(document.getElementById('video').style.display=="block"){

        }
        else{
            document.getElementById('audio').play();
            document.getElementById('pause').style.display="block"; 
            document.getElementById('play').style.display="none";
        }
    }
    else{
        if(document.getElementById('video').style.display=="block"){

        }
        else{
            document.getElementById('audio').pause();
            document.getElementById('pause').style.display="none";
            document.getElementById('play').style.display="block";
        }
    }
}
});
//END IF Space bar is pressed
```

Comment: That's working but `&& document.activeElement != document.getElementByTagName('input')` isn't... why?

Comment: Thanks, this also works, but KooiInc was faster :(, but your answer is correct as well :)