# deactivate spacebar while writing a username in a textfield

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to deactivate the use of space bar while the user is entering his/her username in a textfield.

I tried this code which I got it from here  [deactivate space bar in js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6298978/js-deactivate-spacebar-when-typing-in-textfield) , which did not work at all with me, here is the JS code:

```
$('#checkusername').keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 32) {
        return false;
    }
});
```

and here is my textfield text:

```
<input class="input_field_12em required userUserName" name="userUserName" id="checkusername">
```

Comment: Works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/dtb96/

Comment: What debugging steps have you tried?  Is the keydown handler being called at all (put an alert popup in the function to check)?  If it is being called, what is the value of e.keyCode when the spacebar is pressed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have replaced the `return false;` with `e.preventDefault()` and it's working fine for me:
http://jsfiddle.net/wpJKj/1/

Comment: should also work with `return false;` in all browsers tho, but chrome seems to ignore it, works fine with other browsers.

Comment: i tried to put it but it did not work , the element inspect showed this error on console `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL`

Comment: thank you it worked , i realized its a code conflict with other `jQuery` functions i used , for the record it works on chrome also :)